# display 1st and 10th line of user login

Tags: command-line, ls, who

how to Redirect the list of all the users and their login date/time that are currently logged in into “data.txt” and display 1st and 10th line from data.txt

Comment: Looks like James´s homework. ;)

Comment: What who is james and what are you talking about i want to search a specific line from my file who the hell are you talking about

Comment: This question seems like a Homework question. Care to explain why you want 1st and 10th line specifically ? _Normally_ in a PC you won't get 10 lines.

Comment: means this is just for eg. i want just multiple specific line not 1st and 10th

Comment: its good for me if any body help me because i need help urgently

Comment: hi @serg i tried this but not working    sed –n –e ‘1p’ –e ‘10p’ data.txt   :(

Comment: @prachi  Well then you must be doing something wrong or your file is wrong, because that's a correct command

Comment: means the command which i show you its correct? sed –n –e ‘1p’ –e ‘10p’ data.txt

Comment: @prachi yes , it's a correct command. Although your single quote looks weird. Are you using english keyboard ? That's how my  single quote look like  `sed -n -e '1p' -e '10p'` It's not the one bellow ESC key, it's the one next to Enter key

Comment: @prachi This is the exact same thing asked by another person at the same time. It is obviuosly homework. This site isn't here to get people to do your homework for you.

Comment: No @dobey i got my answer but i tell you truth that m not doing homework any way leave this topic and thank a lot serg  you are so kind person

Comment: @prachi you're welcome. And like others have said, maybe try to ask the teacher or google the solution first, because the stuff you ask is very basic AND has been asked already by another person.  Although   AskUbuntu  is site for questions and answers, we're not really a free homework service. Why I did post , is because you showed effort with that `sed` command, which is good. The other person did not show any effort at all

Comment: Thanks Serg :) i am beginner and try to learn not to do homework

Comment: @prachi very good. Welcome to the site !  Learn well  and help others ,too :)  We're a community after all

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk 'NR==1 && NR==10' FILENAME.txt` where `NR` means number of record aka line number

Comment: can you write full command please

Comment: @prachi just supply the file as argument to the command above